# Web2py: auth user image field Error 2

Tags: python, web2py

I try to add a few extra fields in web2py's auth user register form. The part auth.setting.extra_fields['auth_user'] is what I added to models/db.py

```
auth = Auth(db)

crud, service, plugins = Crud(db), Service(), PluginManager()

auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = [
                                            Field('address'),
                                            Field('city'),
                                            Field('zip'),
                                            Field('image','upload')
                                            ]

## create all tables needed by auth if not custom tables
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)
```

All fields except the image field seem work fine.
But when I try to upload an image to 'Apply Changes',
I got IOERROR Error2 No such file or directory: "....jpg"

The web server runs locally and the image is in my computer.

Am I missing any thing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a new app and add this :

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = [
                                        Field('address'),
                                        Field('city'),
                                        Field('zip'),
                                        Field('image','upload')
                                        ]
```

in app/models/db.py like you did as far as I can see.

Then I create a new user with appadmin and insert a image in my image field of type upload. It worked out of the box with web2py 2.4.7

Maybe provide the version of web2py you use could help to find the issue you face.

Your problem maybe be coming from permissions or web server configuration, but without detailed informations about you setup, I can't help.

Note: You could have more help on the mailing-list here :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py

The community of web2py is very freindly and helping.

Cheers

Richard